# Laravel 7 how to modify $response in sendLoginResponse() function

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, authentication, axios

I am using React to build my frontend application and Laravel 7 with the builtin authentication routes/controllers to build the backend. I can't seem to figure out how to hit the login endpoint using axios from a React component. And also, I should "hide" some links in the frontend for non-admin users (I have implemented Roles in my schema, and created a middleware to check for admin role), but I need the user's role in my Redux state to do so. How can I modify the $response in sendLoginResponse() to add this role information?

```
/**
 * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    if ($response = $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
                ? new Response('', 204)
                : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: You could add a `role` relationship on user model and access it using Eloquent `with('role')` and return that in `$response`, since you already have the user's `id` after authentication.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I can't seem to understand how to add the role to the $response. Do you mean I could just do: $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user()->with('role') and it should do it? Sorry if I'm missing something I'm new to Laravel..